# Userdefined Port Number

Tags: c, sockets, user-defined-functions

I've been trying to modify http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ "selectserver.c" and allow a user defined port number and use it instead of

```
#define PORT "9034"   // port we're listening on
```

i'm trying to make this work...

```
int PORT;
if (argc == 1)  {
    printf("\nNo argument passed. See example: ./selectserver 1234 \n\n");
    exit(-1);
} else {
    PORT = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("PORT NO. : %d \n", PORT);
}

char* ptrPORT = (char *)&PORT;
```

...

here's the code i've modified:

```
/*
** selectserver.c -- a cheezy multiperson chat server
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

//#define PORT "10000"   // port we're listening on

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[] )   {
    int PORT;
    fd_set master;    // master file descriptor list
    fd_set read_fds;  // temp file descriptor list for select() 
    int fdmax;    // maximum file descriptor number
    int listener;     // listening socket descriptor
    int newfd;        // newly accept()ed socket descriptor
    struct sockaddr_storage remoteaddr; // client address
    socklen_t addrlen;
    char buf[256];    // buffer for client data
    int nbytes;

    char remoteIP[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    int yes=1;        // for setsockopt() SO_REUSEADDR, below
    int i, j, rv;

    struct addrinfo hints, *ai, *p;

    FD_ZERO(&master);    // clear the master and temp sets
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);

    // get us a socket and bind it
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    if (argc == 1)  {
        printf("\nNo argument passed. See example: ./selectserver 1234 \n\n" );
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        PORT = atoi(argv[1]);
        printf("PORT NO. : %d \n", PORT);
    }

    char* ptrPORT = (char *)&PORT;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, ptrPORT, &hints, &ai)) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "selectserver: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
            exit(1);
    }

    for(p = ai; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        listener = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
        if (listener < 0) {
            continue;
        }

        // lose the pesky "address already in use" error message
        setsockopt(listener, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int));

        if (bind(listener, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
                close(listener);
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    // if we got here, it means we didn't get bound
    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "selectserver: failed to bind\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(ai); // all done with this

    // listen
    if (listen(listener, 10) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(3);
    }

    // add the listener to the master set
    FD_SET(listener, &master);

    // keep track of the biggest file descriptor
    fdmax = listener; // so far, it's this one

    // main loop
    for(;;) {
        read_fds = master; // copy it
        if (select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
            perror("select");
            exit(4);
        }

        // run through the existing connections looking for data to read
        for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++) {
            if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)) { // we got one!!
                if (i == listener) {
                // handle new connections
                addrlen = sizeof remoteaddr;
                newfd = accept(listener,
                    (struct sockaddr *)&remoteaddr,
                    &addrlen);
                if (newfd == -1) {
                    perror("accept");
                } else {
                    FD_SET(newfd, &master); // add to master set
                    if (newfd > fdmax) {    // keep track of the max
                        fdmax = newfd;
                    }
                    printf("selectserver: new connection from %s on "
                        "socket %d\n",
                        inet_ntop(remoteaddr.ss_family,
                            get_in_addr((struct sockaddr*)&remoteaddr),
                            remoteIP, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN), newfd);
        }
            } else {
                // handle data from a client
                if ((nbytes = recv(i, buf, sizeof buf, 0)) <= 0) {
                    // got error or connection closed by client
                    if (nbytes == 0) {
                        // connection closed
                        printf("selectserver: socket %d hung up\n", i);
                    } else {
                        perror("recv");
                    }
                    close(i); // bye!
                    FD_CLR(i, &master); // remove from master set
                } else {
                    // we got some data from a client
                    for(j = 0; j <= fdmax; j++) {
                        // send to everyone!
                        if (FD_ISSET(j, &master)) {
                            // except the listener and ourselves
                            if (j != listener && j != i) {
                                if (send(j, buf, nbytes, 0) == -1) {
                                    perror("send");
                }
                }
            }
            }
        }

                } // END handle data from client
            } // END got new incoming connection
        } // END looping through file descriptors
    } // END for(;;)--and you thought it would never end!

    return 0;
}
```

And it would compile smoothly.
Now my problem is upon execution it would show this and I honestly have no idea how to fix it(we only had a class discussion yesterday so i'm basically noob about socket programming)

```
./selectserver 10000

PORT NO. : 10000 
selectserver: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

please bear with me thanks!

Comment: Do you really think that `printf("PORT NO. : %d \n", "9034");` would ever produce useful results? You can't pass a string (const char*) variable to a function that expects an integer. How about `int num = "1" + "2"`? Of course that wont work. `int num = 1 + 2;` on the other-hand is an entirely different matter. ;)

Comment: `getaddrinfo` doesn't work this way. Read the man page.

Comment: it's why it used a type cast for it `char* ptrPORT = (char *)&PORT;` so that it won't violate the parameters of `getaddrinfo` hmmm... i don't know what went wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getaddrinfo` takes a pointer to a null terminated character string as the second argument.

```
char* ptrPORT = (char *)&PORT;
```

The above statement is type-casting a pointer to an `int` into a pointer to a char. That does not change the fact that it is still pointing at an `int`.  Now, if you think carefully, you can see that `getaddrinfo` will not know how to read your value correctly - it is not a true null terminated character string.

However, `argv[1]` is a null terminated character string, so my suggestion is to use it as-is instead of trying to convert it:

```
char* ptrPORT = argv[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The service argument accepts both char* and int.
However, do you really want to rely on the recognition between char* and int?
On the man page [enter link description here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) the service argument can be a number as string. When hints.ai_flags is set to AI_NUMERICSERV.